# Press back to go base fragment with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I have two fragments; HomeFragment & NextFragment and I go to the next one with a button from the base fragment. Then via back press I want to go back to the first one, however I end up at the apps home screen. A solution

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher
            .addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                    findNavController().popBackStack()
                }
            })
```

was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70593034/why-i-cannot-go-back-to-previous-fragment-with-navigation-component) but it did not work. I am using ViewPager2 and saw that the home fragment is destroyed when I go to the next one. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried ```findNavController().navigateUp()```?

Comment: Hi, I haven't, where should I put it?

Comment: I tried with the code above but still the app crashes.

Comment: Instead of `findNavController().popBackStack()` try with  `requireActivity().moveTaskToBack(true)`